# Ruby - Calling methods inside an object and using .call()

Tags: ruby

I'm working through "Learn Ruby The Hard Way", and have a question about calling a method inside an object. I'm hoping someone can shed some light on this.

[The code](http://ruby.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex43.html) is:

```
def play()
  next_room = @start

  while true
    puts "\n--------"
    room = method(next_room)
    next_room = room.call()
  end
end
```

I know that the `while` loop in this method is what makes the game continue on to its different areas. My question is, why does `room.call()` have to first be passed to `next_room` for it to work? Why doesn't just doing `room.call()` make the game continue to the next area?

I tested this out myself and I don't understand why it won't work this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`next_room` is a symbol which names the method to be called to figure out which room is next. If we look at one of the room methods, we'll see things like this:

```
def central_corridor()
  #...
  if action == "shoot!"
    #...
    return :death
```

So if you start with `@start = :central_corridor` then in `play`, `next_room` will start as `:central_corridor` and the first iterator of the `while` loop goes like this:

```
room = method(next_room) # Look up the method named central_corridor.
next_room = room.call()  # Call the central_corridor method to find the next room.
```

Suppose you chose to shoot when `room.call()` happens, then `:death` will end up in `next_room`. Then the next iteration through the loop will look up the `death` method through `room = method(next_room)` and execute it.

The [`method`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-method) method is used to convert the symbol in `next_room` to a method, then that method is called to find out what happens next. The *what happens next* part comes from the return value of `room`. So each room is represented by a method and those methods return the name of the method which represents the next room.

Comment: Thanks so much for the in-depth explanation. I understand how this works now!

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple code I created.  With the help of print statements, we're able to visualize what method(next_room) and room.call() do.

```
def printThis()
  puts "thisss"
end

next_room = "printThis"
print "next_room is:  ", next_room; puts


room = method(next_room)
print "room is:  ", room; puts

room.call()
```